# InvokeActionEventListener not working in Omnifaces Showcase in local server

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, wildfly-8, omnifaces, mojarra

I have deployed [Omnifaces Showcase 2.4](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase) in my local server to test `InvokeActionEventListener` because I'm facing some problems with the Flash Scope. Since the showcase `InvokeActionEventListener` was not working I downloaded a clean Wildfly 8.2.0 and deployed it there, and I've got the same results.

Basically the problem is that in the page [eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener) when I click "this link" in the demo section there is no message after redirect occurs, although it  appears correctly in the official Showcase site.

Please find below the log entries from the moments when I open "eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener" page:

```
2016-08-14 11:00:50,796 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flash] (default task-11) JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.
```

When I click "this link":

```
2016-08-14 11:01:11,854 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flash] (default task-13) JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.
2016-08-14 11:01:11,861 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser] (default task-13) HV000007: META-INF/validation.xml found. Parsing XML based configuration.
2016-08-14 11:01:11,885 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationBootstrapParameters] (default task-13) HV000004: Using org.omnifaces.validator.JsfLabelMessageInterpolator as message interpolator.
2016-08-14 11:01:11,896 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13) InvokeActionBean.initParam() INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
2016-08-14 11:01:11,907 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flash] (default task-14) JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Is there any additional step that I must take to use correctly Omnifaces Showcase locally? Maybe server configuration?

Comment: WildFly is known to have trouble with session cookies set by other servers. If you indeed reuse the very same hostname/domain/port across different servers, then you should clear out all cookies on the domain or at least test in an incognito window. Did it help?

Comment: It helped indeed. I was sure I had cleared out the cookies but I didn't. So, should I expect JSF1094 message in my logs every time I restart the server and a client with an active Flash cookie reconnects? BTW, if you write your comment as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: The answer on the abovelinked duplicate already exactly answers this too.